# Contradiction in calculation of barycenter of points with random weight

Tags: statistics, variance

### Defining the barycentre and finding its variance

I have a set of $N$ points at the locations $x_i$ which has weights $W_i$, $i=1,\ldots, N$ and want to find the barycenter (or center of gravity)

$$ B = {\sum_{i=1}^N W_i x_i\over \sum_{i=1}^N W_i}.$$

I want to find the variance of $B$. 
I assume that $W_i$ are i.i.d. and positive with expected value $Ew_i=\mu$ and variance $Var[W_i]=E[w_i-\mu]^2=\sigma^2 $.
I also assume that $N$ is large, so $\sum_{i=1}^N w_i$ is well approximated by $N\mu$ (justified below).

When I do the calculations (see one example below) I end up with 
$$ Var [B] = {\sigma^2 \over  N^2 \mu^2} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2. $$

### The contradiction

As explained below, I think that the barycentre variance should be independent of a shift of all the $x_i$, that is $Var[B]$ should not change if all $x_i$ is shifted to $x_i+c$. But $\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2$, and therefore my estimated $Var[B]$, will change a shift of the $x_i$.

Where is the error: In my calculations, or the expectation that the variance should be independent of shift in $x$.

---

### One derivation of the variance

$$Var [B ]
= Var \left[{\sum_{i=1}^N W_i x_i \over \sum_{i=1}^N w_i}\right]
= {1\over N^2 \mu^2} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2 Var [W_i]
={\sigma^2\over N^2 \mu^2} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2$$

Here I used that $Var [\sum_i X_i] = \sum_i Var[ X_i]$ when the $X_i$ are independent, that $Var [cX]=c^2 Var[X]$, and that $Var[ w_i] =\sigma^2$.

I have also done the same in a more direct fashion, with the same result. It is kind of messy, so I have omitted it.

### Why do I expect $Var [B]$ to be invariant to a shift of $x_i$?

The expected value of $B$ is the mean of the $x_i$:

$$E[B]=E\left[{\sum_{i=1}^N E[W_i] x_i\over \sum_{i=1}^N W_i}\right]
 ={\sum_{i=1}^N E[W_i] x_i\over N\mu}
={\mu\sum_{i=1}^N x_i\over N\mu}={\sum_{i=1}^N x_i\over N}=\bar x_i.$$

Moving all $x_i$ by $c$ will move every barycentre estimate by $c$:
$$ \tilde B = {\sum_{i=1}^N W_i (x_i+c)\over \sum_{i=1}^N W_i}
= {\sum_{i=1}^N W_i x_i\over \sum_{i=1}^N W_i} +{\sum_{i=1}^N W_i c\over \sum_{i=1}^N W_i}=
{\sum_{i=1}^N W_i x_i\over \sum_{i=1}^N W_i} +c=B+c.$$

The variance of $B$ is $Var[B]=E[(B-E[B])^2]$. 
Moving all the $x_i$ by $c$ adds $c$ to $B$ and $E[B]$, so $B-E[B]$ and the variance should stay the same.

To check this I did a [MATLAB simulation](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/30f09acb70b920b63f110bd1de32ee79). In that simulation the estimated variances and barycentres (after i remove the displacement $c$) are identical.

### Why do I think $\sum_{i=1}^N w_i =N\mu$ is a good approximation

Although the variance of $\sum_{i=1}^N w_i$ grow with $N$, this means that the standard deviation grow with $\sqrt N$. 
And since the expected value grow with $N$, the relative spread will decrease.

It is the relative spread that is important for this case. Say that for one $N$ the expected value is 100 and the standard deviation is 1. Then, if $\sum_{i=1}^N w_i $ miss $N\mu$ with one standard deviation my estimate of $B$ is off by 1%. 
If I increase N by a factor of a 100, the expected value will be 10 000 and the standard deviation will be 10. 
So if $\sum_{i=1}^N w_i $ miss $N\mu$ with one standard deviation my estimate of $B$ is off by 0.1%.

Which mean that for large enough N the error will be negligible.

---

### Context

I'm trying to repeat a derivation for the variance of an estimated arrival time from [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5607320/). The barycentre is used to find the time when the echo from the seafloor is received for seabed mapping echo sounder.

As a simplified model, the part of the time sequence used in the barycentre calculation can be modelled as a sequence of independent, identically (Rayleigh) distributed, amplitude values. These amplitude values are equally spaced in time.

In this question the $W_i$ represent the amplitudes, the $x_i$ it the sample times and $B$ is the estimated time of arrival.
The paper states that it can be show analytically that

$$Var[B]= \frac{\Delta x^2}{12(N+1)}\left(\frac{4}{\pi}-1\right)N(N+2),$$

where $\Delta x$ is the distance between the $x_i$ ($x_i=x_0+i \Delta x$).
I have translated the equation to the notation used in this question. 
No reference is given, although I am searching in related papers.

The middle factor in that equation $\left(4/\pi-1\right)$ is equal to the ratio the variance and the mean value squared of a [Rayleigh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) distributed variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of mistakes in your work here.

In your derivation you replace the denominator, $\sum W_i$ with its expectation value. You say you do this because it is a good approximation, but you are ignoring the variance it contributes. Would you still do that if the numerator was a constant? If so, you would have found that $V[\hat{X}]=0$.

The more important issue is that you are assuming the $W_i$ are independent. If we make the replacement,
$$F_i = {W_i\over\sum W_i}$$ 
then,
$$B = \sum x_i F_i$$
Because $\sum F_i = 1$, there are only $n-1$ independent random variables $F_i,\ \  i =2...n$. The other random variable is
$$F_1 = 1 - \sum_{i=2}^{n}F_i$$
Write $B$ in terms of the remaining independent random variables:
$$B = x_1\left(1 - \sum_{i=2}^{n}F_i\right)+\sum_{i=2}^n x_i F_i=x_1+\sum_{i=2}^n (x_i-x_1) F_i$$
Then, 
$$E[B] = x_1 +E[F]\sum_{i=2}^n (x_i-x_1)= x_1 + {1\over n}\sum_{i=2}^n (x_i-x_1) = {1\over n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = \bar{x}$$
and 
$$V[B] = V[F]\sum_{i=2}^n (x_i-x_1)^2$$

For this example the variance is invariant under translation of $x_i$. In reducing the degrees of freedom to $n-1$, the term $x_1$ is treated differently from the rest; note that $V[F_1]=(n-1)V[F]$.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I updated the notation to make my question easier to understand, although not following you completely. I disagree with your two other issues, so I added justification for my claim about the simplification in the denominator and why I expect the variance to change when $x_i\rightarrow x_i+c$. I think my simplification is valid in the denominator, although very bad in the numerator as you point out. I also think the translation $f_i \rightarrow f_i+c$ is impossible since the way $F_i$ is defined $\sum F_i$ must be 1.

Comment: Okay I removed the incorrect side remark about translating $f_i$. It doesn't change the argument. If you reformulate your problem so that the denominator is a constant, it still does not change the argument. The variance for the quantity you now call $B$ comes from the variance of the random variables $F$. Please look at the equation for $\hat{F}$. The variance clearly increases if all $x_i$ are increased. Are you surprised that the variance of $\hat{F}$ is affected when you shift the $x_i$? That equation is equivalent to your equation for B - so the same applies for $B$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't follow. Isn't it such that since $F_i=W_i/\sum W_i$, we have that $\sum F_i=\sum W_i/W_i =1$? Therefore $c\sum F_i=c$ and the last equation in your edited answer is an equality and my argument hold. To check my intuition I did a simulation and the variance were unchanged when I shifted the $x_i$. I added the link to my code in my answer.

Comment: Yes, my answer incorrectly assumed that the $F_i$ were independent. I have edited the answer above to use the $B$ symbol and to treat the $F_i$ correctly. Hopefully now it is clear where the error was made in your calculation...

Comment: Brilliant! This is a huge step forward for my understanding, and it seems correct. I expect that I will accept it as soon as I find the time to work trough it properly. Then I can move on to the problem of finding $V[F]$ now that I have learned that I cannot ignore the variance contribution of the denominator...

Comment: I've found one remaining problem $\sum_{i=2}^n ( x_i-x_1)$ is independent of translation of the $x_i$ but not labelling of the data points (which point is $x_1$). Lets say our $x$ values are 1, 2 and 3. If I say $x_1=1$  then $\sum_{i=2}^n ( x_i-x_1)=(2-1)^2+(3-1)^2 =5$, but if I say $x_1=2$ then $\sum_{i=2}^n ( x_i-x_1)=(1-2)^2+(3-2)^2=2$. The problem may be that the $F_i$ for $i\geq 2$ are not independent. My current guess is that we get $V[B]=V[F]\sum_{i=1}^n ( x_i-\sum_i x_i/N)$ after that is accounted for (Whatever $F$ is defined as then).

Comment: The example treats the first term differently from the rest, thus label invariance does not hold (see last sentence). The initial formulation of this problem asserts that $x_i$ are NOT outcomes of random variables, and the motivation to form a noisy estimator of their simple mean is not stated. It might help to describe the context that this $B$ might be useful. The more typical application (weighted average) is that $x_i$ are outcomes of independent random variables $X_i$ and the weights are not considered outcomes of random variables. In that case the estimator has the properties you expect.

Comment: I added the context of my question, I hope it is helpful. It should explain why  the $x_i$ is not deterministic, and why I named $B$ $\hat x$ initially.   I see why the special treatment of $x_1$ lead to its special place in the variance expression. But since there is nothing in the problem that mandate a particular value to be named $x_1$ a good solution should give the same variance regardless which value is chosen to be $x_1$.

Comment: I find this confusing. Your last comments suggests $x_i$ are not constants, but outcomes of random variable $X_i$. If that is the case, then the formulation of the problem should replace $x_i$ by $X_i$ in your definition of $B$ and the variance of $X_i$ should be included in calculating $V[B]$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should say the $x_i$ is not random (or is deterministic).

Comment: If that is the case, then I go back to my original concern. If they are known constants, form the simple mean of the $x_i$: it has zero variance. You do not motivate why you want to form an estimator that has non-zero variance, when you can calculate it without variance.

Comment: This is a simplified case of a general problem where the mean value of the $W_i$ has a bell shape over $t_i$. Then the falloff of the mean value at the edges will make the expected value independent of the interval of the $t_i$, since the edges will be weighted down. A non centered interval will also be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Through [this PhD thesis](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00783671) (chapter 3.2.3) i found the following solution.

For simplicity, define 
$$F_i = {W_i\over\sum W_i}, \text{ so that } B=\sum_{i=1}^N F_i x_i.$$ 
(As Deans answer suggest)

Then 
$$E[(B-E[B])^2]={\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N (x_i-\bar x) (x_j-\bar x) E[(F_i-E[F_i]) (F_j-E[F_j])} $$
$${=\sum_{i=1}^N  (x_i-\bar x)^2 E[(F_i-E[F_i])^2]}
{=\sum_{i=1}^N  (x_i-\bar x)^2 Var[F_i]}$$
if we assume that the $F_i$ are uncorrelated. $\bar x$ is the mean of the $x_i$.

The first step holds since
$${\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N (x_i-\bar x) (x_j-\bar x) E[(F_i-E[F_i]) (F_j-E[F_j])}=E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i-\bar x) (F_i-E[F_i])\right)^2\right],$$
and
$$\sum_{i=1}^N (x_i-\bar x) (F_i-E[F_i])=\sum_{i=1}^N( x_iF_i-x_iE[F_i]) + \bar x \sum_{i=1}^N(E[F_i]-F_i)=B-E[B].$$
Where I used that $\sum_{i=1}^NE[F_i]=1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^NF_i=1$.